# How to validate object attribute added like that: MyObj.newattribute = 123

Tags: python, class, validation, object, oop

In my code (python) I have a class defined as follows:

```
class Properties:

    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        self.otherproperty = kwargs.get("otherproperty")
        self.channel = kwargs.get("channel")

        if self.channel not in "A":
            print("bad channel input - it should be A")
        pass
```

In the rest of my code, in various places I calculate and add various attributes to the instance of that class:

```
prop = Properties()
prop.channel="B"
#lots of calculations here
prop.otherproperty= "not a channel"
```

But when I do it this way, I get an error: `TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not NoneType` 
I already figured out that the following way I have no issues, and the new attribute gets nicely validated, and the user is informed that `prop.channel` should be different :

```
prop = Properties(otherproperty = "not a channel",channel="B")
```

But because of several reasons it would be inconvenient to define `prop` object this way.

So how do I validate the object's attributes when I'm adding them step-by-step? And how is such step-by-step object building professionally named?

Comment: Perhaps you want `if prop.channel is None or prop.channel not in "A":`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a custom setter for the channel property with [Python descriptors](https://realpython.com/python-descriptors/):

```
class Properties:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.otherproperty = kwargs.get("otherproperty")
        self._channel = None  # Private attribute for channel

    @property
    def channel(self):
        return self._channel

    @channel.setter
    def channel(self, value):
        if value not in "A":
            raise ValueError("Bad channel input, it must be a substring of 'A'")
        self._channel = value
```

The example usage would be:

```
prop = Properties()
prop.channel = "B"  # Raises ValueError
```

This way of gradually adding attributes to an object can be called "lazy object initialization" and is useful if you want to avoid long computations before creating an object.

Side note: the above code doesn't raise an error if you set `prop.channel = ""`. So you might want to change the validation to `if value != "A":` if this was an unintended behavior.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Pydantic](https://docs.pydantic.dev/dev/) for data validation.
To validate on assignments, you need to set `validate_assignment` to `True`.

```
from typing import Any
from pydantic import BaseModel
from pydantic import ConfigDict
from pydantic import field_validator
from pydantic import Field

class Props(BaseModel):
    model_config = ConfigDict(validate_assignment=True)

    channel: str | None = None
    other : str | None = Field(None, min_length=3)

    @field_validator("channel")
    @classmethod
    def validate_channel(cls, v: str | None) -> str:
        if v is None or v != "A":
            raise ValueError('Should be "A".')

        return v
```

This adds a validator for `channel` that only accepts `A`.

```
p = Props()
p.channel = 'A' # works
p.channel = 'B' # raise ValueError
```

There are also a lot of ways to use in-built validators, for example a `min_length` on the property `other`:

```
p.other = 'abc' # works
p.other = 'a' # raises ValidationError
```

Comment: Cool but introduces more complex syntax (typing) and a dependency (Pydantic)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to define the attributes with a default value, you could override `__setattr__`:

```
from typing import Any, Callable
from functools import cached_property


class Props:
    def __setattr__(self, __name: str, __value: Any) -> None:
        if __name in self._validators:
            self._validators[__name](__value)

        super().__setattr__(__name, __value)

    def _validate_channel(self, v: str):
        if v != 'A':
            raise ValueError('Should be "A".')

    @cached_property
    def _validators(self) -> dict[str, Callable]:
        return {
            "channel": self._validate_channel,
        }

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        attrs = ",".join(
            [f"{k}={v}" for k, v in self.__dict__.items() if not k.startswith("_")]
        )
        return f"Props({attrs})"

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return self.__str__()
```

If you try to assign a value, then `__setattr__` is called and you can run your validation.

```
p = Props()
p.channel = 'A' # works
p.channel = 'B' # raises ValueError
```